# How to replace surrogate code point characters with regex_replace in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

My requirement is to strip surrogate code point characters from a Postgres column, because they are invalid XML characters and the data needs to be correct in XML. For example, these type of characters:

```
ubuntu@instenv-226703-n3fe:/Attachments$ awk '{FS="&"} {print $2 $3}' code.txt | sort
#55357;#56443; Order approved"" view=""fieldscreen"">
#55357;#56443; Request Approval Level 3"">
#55357;#56443; Request Board Approval Level"">
```

Now I have a regex which matches these:

```
[\x{D800}-\x{DBFF}][\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]
```

but it doesn't work directly in regex_replace SQL:

```
regexp_replace(descriptor, '[\x{D800}-\x{DBFF}][\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]', '', 'g');

ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence 
SQL state: 2201B
```

Is there some way to use this regex in the postgres function?
Thanks